# JQuery focus works weird on password fields in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

I made a login form with username and password. 
The Username and password fields have placeholders. and I fixed the IE problem of not recognizing the placeholder attribute, by using Jquery to remove textbox value on focus. and for the password I made a hidden input type=password textbox, and I made a textbox with input type=text with value="password" that when clicked it hides and the password field is shown.
here's the form's html code:

```
<form method="post" action="check.php">
    <input type="text" class="login-textbox" id="enter-username" placeholder="Username" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="text" class="login-textbox" id="password-placeholder" placeholder="Password" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="password" class="login-textbox" id="enter-password" maxlength="50"/>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Login" />
</form>
```

here's the JQuery code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#enter-username").val("Username");

    $("#password-placeholder").val("Password");

    $("#enter-username").focus(function(){
        if($(this).val()=="Username"){
            $(this).val("");$(this).css("color","#000000");
        }
        $(this).css("border","2px solid #00A2E8");
    });

    $("#enter-username").blur(function(){
        if($(this).val()==""){
            $(this).val("Username");$(this).css("color","#808080");
        }
        $(this).css("border","2px solid #D8D8D8");
    });

    $("#password-placeholder").focus(function(){
        $(this).hide();$("#enter-password").show();
        $("#enter-password").focus();
    });

    $("#enter-password").focus(function(){
        $("#enter-password").css("border","2px solid #00A2E8");
    });

    $("#enter-password").blur(function(){
        if($(this).val()==""){
            $(this).hide();$("#password-placeholder").show();
        }
        $(this).css("border","2px solid #D8D8D8");
    });
});
```

This works fine on chrome and  internet explorer, but on firefox, when I click (focus) on the password text box the password field shows with text in it. like this:

[image: password problem]

The password field should be empty when I click on it. anybody knows how can I fix this?

Comment: you dont need all this code. just use jquery placeholder plugin for older ie's..

Comment: All of this just for IE, I advise you to use placeholder attribute and forget about IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you are setting the value for those `input`

```
$("#enter-username").val("Username");
$("#password-placeholder").val("Password");
```

Remove these lines and your code will work just fine.

Also change type of password input field from `text` to `password` like

```
<input type="password" class="login-textbox" id="password-placeholder" placeholder="Password" maxlength="50"/>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ceCY/)

---

**Update**

Change code to

```
$("#enter-password").focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Password") {
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).css("color", "#000000");
    }
    $(this).css("border", "2px solid #00A2E8");
});

$("#enter-username").focus(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Username") {
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).css("color", "#000000");
    }
    $(this).css("border", "2px solid #00A2E8");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ceCY/1/)

Comment: But I need the values for the lower versions of IE that don't have placeholder so people know that this field is for username and this field is for password.